# Why is my icon not showing upin html and instead showing a bordered square?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web, icons

As aforementioned in the title, I used the website FontAwesome to get an icon I then attempted to display this with the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Loading....</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./starting.css"></link>
</head>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1f2023aaf1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
<i id="fa" class="fa fa-regular fa-spinner fa-xl"></i>"></i>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried making it bigger with `fa-xl` and just adding the `fa` class. But that didn't work either.

Comment: What is this `</i>"></i>`?

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input
Your HTML is invalid  - stray `</link>` (self closing tag), Script between head and body, `"></i>` does not belong there, `fa-regular` might not be valid

Answer (score 0):

You are adding some extra links

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Loading....</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./starting.css"></link>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1f2023aaf1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <i id="fa" class="fa fa-regular fa-spinner fa-xl"></i> <!-- this was modified -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `</link>` is also invalid

Comment: Script between head and body also illegal

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your html and remove `fa-regular`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Loading....</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./starting.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1f2023aaf1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <i id="fa" class="fa fa-spinner fa-xl"></i>
</body>
</html>
```